# Generate Rows And Columns from Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a small predicament.

I have a table called users. The table users has relationship with another table called user notification. Here is the migration for the user table:

```
create_table "user_notifications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.belongs_to :user
    t.integer "other_user"
    t.integer  "unseen_count",    default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
  end
```

The problem is that when I create a new user then the table is populated with the row of the new user. How do I add the row to all the existing users. It is needed for the function of the app. Also I am using putty to connect to the server so the only tool I have is the rails console.

Example: I have 60 users. How do I have it so all 60 users get a row in the new table using the rails console.

Edit: This is the method I use whenever a user is signed up. Can I use this method within the rails console or create a deviation of this?

user.rb:

```
after_create :create_user_notification    

def create_user_notification
  UserNotification.create(:user_id => self.id)
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by

`How do I add the row to all the existing users`

Comment: As In I have 60 users. The new table has a relationship with the user table. How do I create a row for all 60 users. Sorry for not being clear

Comment: how do you know what you want to relate to this users, there has to be a foreign key that identifies what user owns what row in the new table, your question is still vague after the edit

Comment: I added the migration I used. So they both share the Id of user_id. The row for the user is created when a new user is created. The problem is I have old users where the row isn't made (needs to be created). How Do I go about creating a bunch of rows for all 60 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to add a notification to each user record.

Given that you have models that look something like this:

```
class User
  has_many :user_notifications
end

class UserNotification
  belongs_to :user
end
```

To insert a record for each user you would do something like this:

```
User.all.find_in_batches(batch_size: 10).each do |u|
  u.user_notifications.create(message: 'Hello dear')
end
```

`.find_in_batches` might not really matter if you have 60 records but if you have 60,000 your server will run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks, quick question. Do I enter this into a new migration or the rails console?

Comment: I would do this in the console as a migration is really just for altering the database schema and this is a one-off task.

Comment: Thank you again for the help. I am getting this error `undefined method assert_valid_keys' for 10:Fixnum`

Comment: Oops. Edited should be `find_in_batches(batch_size: 10)`

Comment: I am having another error pop up. It's saying `NoMethodError: undefined method `user_notifications' for #<Array:0x000000058cad20>`

Comment: @Jakxna360 look at the documentation for [`find_in_batches`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches) inside the `do` block should be `u.each { |user| user.user_notifications.create(message: 'Hello dear') }`

Comment: So I am still getting this error. For the user model I have a method called create_user_notification that works when the user is created. Can I call that within rails console?

Comment: Ah... I reread the link and I figured it out. Thanks a lot man : )

Comment: Sorry, should have tested it but I'm in the middle of reinstalling everything - the error was probably just that find_in_batches hands the batch to the iterator instead of the records as I though. Glad it worked out